# How do I set a rescue email for my AppleID after I have set up 2-factor authentication?

Tags: iphone, email, security, apple-id, two-factor-authentication

I have set up two-factor authentication on my iPhone as a security setting, however, just to be safe (in case I ever lose access to this phone/number) I'd also like to set up a rescue email.

Unfortunately, once I set the 2FA, the option to set a rescue email has disappeared from the menu.

My question is, where can I find this option?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set a rescue email when you have enabled 2-factor authentication (2FA).

The rescue mail is used if you forget your security questions - then you can use the rescue mail to reset them. However, when you enable 2FA, you do not have security questions anymore.

All in all you get the better security with 2FA (compared to not enabling 2FA), and it is a benefit that you do not have to set a rescue email anymore.